# Ms Access 2016 Reporting - table data as column headers

Tags: vba, reporting, ms-access-2016

I am using Ms Access2016 to collect and process data from multiple users.
I need to create a report showing the statuses of reviews for a rolling 3 month period.

I have a query that gets the relevant data which is held:

```
Product    Status     Date
ProdA      Green      Feb-2018
ProdA      Red        Jan-2018
ProdA      Red        Dec-2017
ProdB      Green      Feb-2018
ProdB      Green      Jan-2018
ProdB      Red        Dec-2017
```

I need a report where the column headers are the distinct date values, below this are the statuses for the relevant products e.g.

```
Product     Dec-2017    Jan-2018     Feb-2018
ProdA       Red         Red          Green
ProdB       Red         Green        Green
```

I can create something similar in Excel but really want to keep it all together in Access. Is this possible and if so how? Does anyone have a link to any guides on this - I haven't been able to find anything that helps but probably searching for the wrong thing.

Comment: You will need a crosstab query for that: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8

Comment: Thank you for you quick answer. I have tried it and it works almost perfectly - the only part I'm stuck on now is that the values shown are a count of the Status and not the actual status it self. I cant work out how to change this to the actual value and not a count/calculation. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Try this as the source of your crosstab query:

```
TRANSFORM First(T.Status) AS Status
SELECT T.Product
FROM T
GROUP BY T.Product
PIVOT T.Date;
```

Where `T` is your table name.

Comment: This all works for me expect for one thing, I've noticed that the column headers can not be more than 64 characters long. Some of the fields I am  using for the headers contain 100+ characters. Is there a way to get the full field content as the header?

Comment: In a few words no I'm afraid. https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/access-2010-specifications-1e521481-7f9a-46f7-8ed9-ea9dff1fa854